# Sending SolrInputDocument to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

As part of an upgrade tool, I have files with billions of SolrInputDocument documents which I want to index at max speed on ElasticSearch.
My current plan is to translate them to JSON and use the elastic batch updates to upload them.  However I didn't find an easy way to convert them.
Any information on code / methods / tools for such conversion & uploading will be appreciated.

Possible solution which worked for me (for simple cases not including child documents):

```
Map<String, Object> solrDocToMap(SolrInputDocument sid) {
    Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (SolrInputField field : sid) {
        json.put(field.getName(), field.getValue());
    }
    return json;
}
```

Can do the same with: XContentFactory.jsonBuilder() from elastic client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a tool that allows you to do that, basically a Solr UpdateRequestProcessor that sends the Solr docs to ES. You can check the code [here](https://github.com/jmlucjav/esURP).

You can look at how the code converts Solr docs to ES, and start off that.